# Elasticsearch: Scoring with Ngrams

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, settings, partial, scoring

I have a straight forward question where I have incorporated ngram's for partial matchings. The implementation works well but the score results aren't working as I hoped. I would like my score results to look something like this:

- Ke: .1
- Kev: .2
- Kevi: .3
- Kevin: .4

Instead I am getting the following results where the scoring is the same if there is a match for the field:

- Ke: .4
- Kev: .4
- Kevi: .4
- Kevin: .4

Settings:

```
 settings: {
    analysis: {
      filter: {
        ngram_filter: {
          type: 'edge_ngram',
          min_gram: 2,
          max_gram: 15
        }
      },
      analyzer: {
        ngram_analyzer: {
          type: 'custom',
          tokenizer: 'standard',
          filter: [
            'lowercase',
            'ngram_filter'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Mappings:

```
mappings: [{
          name: 'voter',
          _all: {
                'type': 'string',
                'analyzer': 'ngram_analyzer',
                'search_analyzer': 'standard'
             },
             properties: {
                last: {
                   type: 'string',
                   required : true,
                   include_in_all: true,
                   analyzer: 'ngram_analyzer',
                   search_analyzer: 'standard'
                },
                first: {
                   type: 'string',
                   required : true,
                   include_in_all: true,
                   analyzer: 'ngram_analyzer',
                   search_analyzer: 'standard'
                },

             }

       }]
```

Query:

```
GET /user/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "_all": {
               "query": "Ke",
               "operator": "and"

           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve that using an [`edgeNGram` tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) instead of an `edgeNGram` filter:

```
 settings: {
    analysis: {
      tokenizer: {
        ngram_tokenizer: {
          type: 'edge_ngram',
          min_gram: 2,
          max_gram: 15
        }
      },
      analyzer: {
        ngram_analyzer: {
          type: 'custom',
          tokenizer: 'ngram_tokenizer',
          filter: [
            'lowercase'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The reason for this is that the `edgeNGram` filter will write the terms for a given token at the same position (pretty much like synonyms would do), while the `edgeNGram` tokenizer will create tokens which have different positions, hence influencing the length normalization, hence the score.

Note that this works only on pre-2.0 ES releases, because a compound score is computed from all ngram tokens scores, whereas in ES 2.x only the matching token is scored.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question! I made the following changes above as mentioned by you and still received the same scores for sub matches and exact matches. Do I need to change anything in the mappings as well? Are you able to re create this same scenario on your end? Thank you :)

Comment: Have you wiped your index and re-indexed all your data?

Comment: Yes I have @val .. I wonder why it is still showing the same score for Ke, Kev, Kevi, Kevin

Comment: I do get different scores when matching `Ke` (0.15342641), `Kev` (0.2169777), `Kevi` (0.26574233) and `Kevin` (0.30685282)

Comment: Please explain the steps you went through in order to rebuild your index?

Comment: Are you using standard search analyzer? I am sure that I am closing the cluster and starting a new one with past indexes wiped while trying to solve this issue.

Comment: Im curious to know if you tried using my original implementation on your end if you would get the same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99884/discussion-between-val-and-emarel).

Comment: term vector results:
         "terms": {
            "mo": {
               "term_freq": 1,
               "tokens": [
                  {
                     "position": 0,
                     "start_offset": 0,
                     "end_offset": 2
                  }
               ]
            },
            "mor": {
               "term_freq": 1,
               "tokens": [
                  {
                     "position": 1,
                     "start_offset": 0,
                     "end_offset": 3
                  }
               ]
            }